# Java Regex How to get 2 decimal valu out of alphanumeric string

Tags: java, regex

Hey guys I have a java file not java script 
my line.tostring() is something like this area = 1.446097987730157 m2 and i would need to get only the 1.44 value

```
String inputLine = line.toString();
    String regex = "\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?";
    String replace = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputLine); 
    inputLine = m.replaceAll(replace);
dataArray[0] = inputLine;
```

This is what i get  obviously

```
area = m
```

And I need to get only

```
1.44
```

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Please demonstrate minimal efforts. We don't encourage questions that don't show minimal research.

Comment: @A4L I'm sure he means a java code snippet.

Comment: well, the regex `/\d+\.\d{2}/` will match it in _this_ special case (escape backslashes to use it in java). However, you might have to specify what is a valid input.

Comment: @please don't change the question like that since some it may no longer reflect what's in some answers which will make them prone for down votes. If you tried something that didn't work just add it.

Comment: ok, sorry, also I tried your below code and i get '1.44 with the ' in front of the 1.44..i dont understand

Comment: @Lethal420 I don't understand either, did you copy/paste the exact code? please check the output that it is not adding anything to the result. the regexp matches only digits and a dot, nothing more. please retry to copy/paste the whole code. PS: to notify someone preppend a `@` before the username :)

Comment: Thanks alot for you<r patience..Ultimatly I am using the output to create a cell for an ExcelFile I'm generating with JExcelAPI so I'm guessing it's the API that enters the ' .... Thank you anyhow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following for 2 decimal point precision

```
String inputLine = "12.10654";
String regex = "\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?";    
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputLine);   
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

and the output is `12.10`

Comment: Great but I'm replacing what i want lol with my empty replace string, so I'm guessing using the replaceAll function isn't the best? nice Talon avatar

Comment: almost there I'm getting area = m instead of 1.44

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
@Test
public void find2Dec() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d{0,2})+?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("area = 1.446097987730157 3.1415 m2");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()) {
        String g = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(g);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

output is

```
1.44
3.14
area = 6097987730157 15 m2
```